# Writing continious numpy array in raw representation via socket

Tags: python, arrays, sockets, raw

I need to send big fixed sized buffers from python to c/c++ code side.
From python side I have buffers in form of:

```
array = np.zeros([1000], dtype=np.uint8)
array = fill(array)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 1010))
```

Code below is used to recv data from connected socket from C/C++ side.From the c/c++ side I need to have this buffer as raw 1000 byte array, I don't need any headers, I need just data. Unfortunately I haven't found howto do it. In general `np.tofile()`- makes things I need but in file.

```
int recvBuffer(uint8_t *p_buff, uint32_t size, int socket)
{
    uint32_t recived = 0;
    uint8_t *p_curr = p_buff;
    while (recived < size)
    {
        int ret = recv(tcp_sock, p_curr, size - recived, 0);
        if (ret != -1)
        {
            p_curr += ret;
            recived += ret;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What did you try to make your `np.array` raw? I do not think C/C++ magically distinguish numpy data and convert them into integers. I think you need to explicitly serialize it to bytes or (I have not tried but) try `ctypes`.

Comment: By raw I mean C-like array stype. np.arra(...,dtype =np.uint8) - internally is array of uint8_t values.

Comment: I do not think so. `np.array` is higher-order object. E.g., does not it have `.shape` property? It contains numeric values and much more for efficiency and effectiveness. You cannot directly send such things unless NumPy C API supports de-serializatoin (I do not know about this but it seems not promising). So you would better serialize your data. `[# row : int, # columns : int, type of numeric, numeric, ..., numeric]`. If sparse, serialization should be done in a different manner.

Comment: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.load.html

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
I found it in np.tofile description.

```
np_array = np.zeros([1000], dtype=np.uint8)
np_array = fill(np_array)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 1010))
raw_buffer = np_array.to_bytes()
s.send(raw_buffer)
```

Makes exactlty what I wanted. `raw_buffer` - holds np.array buffer as raw c-stype buffer.

Comment: How did you de-serialize it from C side?

Comment: I have fixed size buffers(raw video images), so C side code is written above in `recvBuffer`